# More than one list of character for one IRREP in character tables

Tags: solid-state-physics, group-theory, representation-theory

I would like to know why in the group $C_4$ (please see http://symmetry.jacobs-university.de/cgi-bin/group.cgi?group=204&option=4) there are two lists of characters for the irreducible representation E? If we may have freedom of choose for either of them, which list can be used for quadratic and cubic functions? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$C_4$ is Abelian with 4 elements so there are $4$ 1-dimensional irreps. Your table correctly lists $4$ sets of characters.  The last two sets of characters are complex conjugate one to the other, and complex conjugation does not produce an equivalence so you do really have 4 sets of characters as you should.

In [their source paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed072p505?casa_token=2uvE5bzPYp4AAAAA:ixr5Ri1l-R0Tb43nleicxO-4kZbrpLwM0y3TgXinm3JwyENYkOocrnPF8pOHAojKZhTSXMuVIcShdiw9)

> Gelessus A, Thiel W, Weber W. Multipoles and symmetry. Journal of chemical education. 1995 Jun;72(6):505.

the authors use the convention that

“the z axis is the $C_n$ axis and transforms as A or B, whereas the degenerate x and y coordinates transform as E.”

so I don’t think A,B and E are irreps, rather just ways of denoting certain combination of coordinates: the authors use in their papers $\Gamma$ for representations.  It just so happens that in some cases these combinations coincide with irreps.

I suspect that, for their purposes, only the quadratic or cubic combinations of the E coordinates will occur so taking $(x+iy)$ or $(x-iy)$ to define E makes no difference.

Comment: The notation E for IR denotes two dimensional IR (Group theory, Mildred Dresselhaus, chapter 5) and also from the form of the basis functions for the irreducible representation E, which includes two basis functions, it seems that E is really a 2D IR.

Comment: the difficulty is that, as $C_4$ is abelian, all irreps are 1-dimensional (at least over $\mathbb{C}$).  It could be you are somehow restricted to the reals but that’s not obvious from the context.